# Google charts timeline change axis

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Im using google timeline to display the hours an employee has worked on each day.  I want to set the x axis to always display 24 hours, but I cannot find how to do that, or if that is possible. it automatically changes it to only display from the earliest to latest points.

Example:

[image]

Comment: The Timeline Visualization does not yet support controlling the time axis.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Charts version 43](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes?hl=en#october-2-2015) (released October 2, 2015) supports minValue and maxValue for the horizontal axis:

```
....

var options = {
  hAxis: {
    minValue: new Date(1785, 0, 0),
    maxValue: new Date(1816, 0, 0)
  }
};

....
```

You have to load it via the [frozen version loader](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements#frozen-versions) though since apparently it [wasn't successfully deployed by the usual process](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-visualization-api/6Gexd2lr8vU/fj32KG08BwAJ).

It looks like minValue and maxValue works only for putting spacing at the beginning and end of the timeline.  So if you specify a minValue that is later than the start date of one of your data points, the timeline still starts at that data point and not at the minValue.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o27ttyy3) that shows minValue and maxValue providing spacing at the beginning and end of the first Google Timeline example: https://jsfiddle.net/o27ttyy3